# Get a string from any API using Chainlink Large Response Example

Tags: oracle, solidity, chainlink

I just need to get a string from this json, for example: https://filesamples.com/samples/code/json/sample1.json

I took the Chainlink example and just change the URL and path. The example works fine, but if you use a different json o jobid it do not work.

Link to chainlink example: https://docs.chain.link/docs/large-responses/

Is there any way to solve this?

Code used:

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.7;

import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/ChainlinkClient.sol";

/**
 * @notice DO NOT USE THIS CODE IN PRODUCTION. This is an example contract. 
 */
contract GenericLargeResponse is ChainlinkClient {
  using Chainlink for Chainlink.Request;

  // variable bytes returned in a signle oracle response
  bytes public data;
  string public dataS;

  /**
   * @notice Initialize the link token and target oracle
   * @dev The oracle address must be an Operator contract for multiword response
   *
   *
   * Kovan Testnet details: 
   * Link Token: 0xa36085F69e2889c224210F603D836748e7dC0088
   * Oracle: 0xc57B33452b4F7BB189bB5AfaE9cc4aBa1f7a4FD8 (Chainlink DevRel)
   *
   */
  constructor(
  ) {
    setChainlinkToken(0xa36085F69e2889c224210F603D836748e7dC0088);
    setChainlinkOracle(0xc57B33452b4F7BB189bB5AfaE9cc4aBa1f7a4FD8);
  }

  /**
   * @notice Request variable bytes from the oracle
   */
  function requestBytes(
  )
    public
  {
    bytes32 specId = "7a97ff8493ec406d90621b2531f9251a";
    uint256 payment = 100000000000000000;
    Chainlink.Request memory req = buildChainlinkRequest(specId, address(this), this.fulfillBytes.selector);
    req.add("get","https://filesamples.com/samples/code/json/sample1.json");
    req.add("path", "fruit");
    requestOracleData(req, payment);
  }

  event RequestFulfilled(
    bytes32 indexed requestId,
    bytes indexed data
  );

  /**
   * @notice Fulfillment function for variable bytes
   * @dev This is called by the oracle. recordChainlinkFulfillment must be used.
   */
  function fulfillBytes(
    bytes32 requestId,
    bytes memory bytesData
  )
    public
    recordChainlinkFulfillment(requestId)
  {
    emit RequestFulfilled(requestId, bytesData);
    data = bytesData;
    dataS = string(data);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The response of that API is:

```json
{
  "fruit": "Apple",
  "size": "Large",
  "color": "Red"
}
```

The `fruit` has a value of `Apple`. You'll need to have the API return the bytes edition of `Apple` instead.

You'll notice the example returns JSON that looks like:

```json
{
  "image": "0x68747470733a2f2f697066732e696f2f697066732f516d5358416257356b716e3259777435444c336857354d736a654b4a4839724c654c6b51733362527579547871313f66696c656e616d653d73756e2d636861696e6c696e6b2e676966"
}
```

Which is the hex edition of the URL of the image.

Comment: Patrick, First of all , thanks for your response. Like the api must return a bytes version of the variable, i created this api that returns a hex version of the word "team1". 
Json: https://flaskserver-327221.rj.r.appspot.com/oracle
Path used: "winner"
It stills not working with this parameters. What can be wrong?

Comment: This is the Kovan contract address 0x7A42B0e3A0F5A4d63F632143739b192E656c8d76

Comment: `7465616d31` is not valid bytes. It must start with `0x`